# Did Ram and Sita get united in the end?

Tags: ramayana

Bhagwan Ram abadoned Mata Sita and she had to live in the forest.

I want to know what happened in the end ?
Did Ram and Sita get united in the end ?
Did Ram forgave Sita and restored her as queen ?

What happened in the end ?

Did Ram accept Luv and Kush in the end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sita was merged unto Goddess Bhumi, so Rama and Sita aren't reunited at the end.

> “If, in thought, I have never dwelt on any but Rama, may the Goddess Madhavi [i.e., The Earth Goddess, also called Dharani] receive me!”
>
> As Vaidehi was still speaking, a miracle took place and, from the earth rose a marvellous celestial throne supported on the heads of Nagas of immeasurable power, their bodies adorned with divine gems. The Goddess Dharani, bidding her welcome, took Maithili in her arms, causing her to be seated on that celestial seat and, while she occupied the throne, a shower of blossoms fell without ceasing from the sky. Then the Gods burst into loud acclamations, crying “Excellent! Excellent! O Sita, your virtue is supreme!”

***Course: Ramayana, Uttara Khanda, Chapter 97***

But, Rama accepts Lava-Kusha and the same chapter mentiones it.

> I acknowledge these twins, Kusha and Lava, to be my sons! I desire to make my peace with the chaste Maithili amidst the assembly.”

---

Ok, that's it. I hope your doubt was cleared.

Comment: Thanks. So, Rama didn't paradon/forgive Sita ? Can you quote where it is written that he accepted Luv and Kush ?

Comment: Ok, i edited that. Also, Actually, Rama is come to ask that is Sita pardon him, but she was merged unto the earth.